# Converting gray scale image to BW image

Tags: image, matlab

I want to convert a gray scale image (uint16) to a black and white image.

```
[level, ] = graythresh(I);
I_bw      = im2bw(I, level);
```

Below the image *I*:
[image]

I don't understand how is possible that image *I_bw* result as follows:
[image]

Note that *level* is equal to 0 after calling *graythresh(I)*.

EDIT: I have uploaded the .mat file containing the original image.
[file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26978291/Image.mat)

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the correct `I`? Using the image you have provided I get a level of `0.5137`: `I = imread('http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vch35.jpg');level=graythresh(I);im2bw(I,level);`

Comment: I am sure. I have uploaded the .JPG version, not the raw one. Can I upload a .fig file?

Comment: Well then how can we test anything? Please upload the image you are working with.

Comment: Is there a way to upload a .mat file or a .fig file?

Comment: Well a .fig file isn't going to be much help here because that's not really an input to anything. You could upload a .mat file to google drive or dropbox or something. You could also try saving as PNG (lossless compression)

Comment: Done. I have thought also to a .fig file since it is possible extract values from it. However I have uploaded the original .mat file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117823/discussion-between-alessandro-and-suever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is: level = 0

```
load Image.mat

I = z;
figure;imshow(I, []);

[level, ] = graythresh(I); %level = 0
I_bw      = im2bw(I, level);
figure;imshow(I_bw);impixelinfo
```

The following code works:
Convert `I` to `double`, and normalize it to range [0, 1].

```
load Image.mat

I = z;
figure;imshow(I, []);

I = double(I)/double(max(I(:))); %Convert to double, and divide by maximum value - set range to [0, 1].

[level, ] = graythresh(I);

I_bw      = im2bw(I, level);
figure;imshow(I_bw);impixelinfo
```

Result:
[image]

The following code works as well:

```
load Image.mat

I = z;
figure;imshow(I, []);

I = double(I)/double(max(I(:))); %Convert to double, and divide by maximum value - set range to [0, 1].
I = uint16(I*2^16-1); %Expand range to [0, 2^16-1] and convert to uint16.

[level, ] = graythresh(I);

I_bw      = im2bw(I, level);
figure;imshow(I_bw);impixelinfo
```

Understanding why level = 0, in the original code requires farther investigation...

Comment: @Alessandro I updated my answer, but I still don't know why level = 0.